# Problem with contrasts of interaction

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

I have a problem with the contrasts for an interaction term in `summary.lm` in `R`. `Type` is a factor with 4 levels (1,2,3,4) and `Ash` is a binary covariate, all other covariates are numeric.

```
lm1 <- lm(P~Type+Ash+Ra+Type:Ash+Type:Ra+Type:Ca,
          data=Data, contrasts=list(Type="contr.Sum"))
summary(lmFin)
Call:
lm(formula = P ~ Type + Ash + Ra + Type:Ash + 
    Type:Ra + Type:Ca, data = Data, contrasts = list(Type = "contr.Sum"))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.00073 -0.23862  0.00252  0.21674  1.14347 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    -3.061e+00  1.382e-01 -22.151  < 2e-16 ***
Type[S.1]      -1.473e+00  1.792e-01  -8.220 3.52e-15 ***
Type[S.2]       1.863e-01  2.785e-01   0.669 0.503967    
Type[S.3]       6.848e-01  2.552e-01   2.683 0.007621 ** 
Ash2           -8.920e-02  3.448e-02  -2.587 0.010061 *  
Ra              9.609e-02  8.927e-03  10.764  < 2e-16 ***
Type[S.1]:Ash2 -2.096e-01  5.968e-02  -3.511 0.000501 ***
Type[S.2]:Ash2 -1.387e-01  5.970e-02  -2.323 0.020729 *  
Type[S.3]:Ash2  1.279e-01  5.999e-02   2.132 0.033692 *  
Type[S.1]:Ra    8.183e-02  1.581e-02   5.176 3.73e-07 ***
Type[S.2]:Ra   -2.939e-02  1.604e-02  -1.832 0.067730 .  
Type[S.3]:Ra   -4.299e-02  1.525e-02  -2.819 0.005084 ** 
Type1:Ca        4.932e-04  1.549e-04   3.184 0.001576 ** 
Type2:Ca       -3.800e-05  1.500e-04  -0.253 0.800104    
Type3:Ca       -4.225e-05  1.639e-04  -0.258 0.796738    
Type4:Ca       -3.235e-04  1.749e-04  -1.849 0.065247 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.336 on 368 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7782,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7692 
F-statistic: 86.08 on 15 and 368 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

**Why doesn't** `contr.Sum` **work for the interaction** `Type:Ca`**?** (I guess it is because I don't have a main effect of `Ca`, but I can't explain why.)

Upd:
example:

```
set.seed(1)
x<-rnorm(100)
y<-rpois(100,1)
y<-as.factor(y)
z<-rnorm(100,10)
lm1<-lm(x~y+y:z)
summary(lm1)


Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  -0.5935     1.2270  -0.484   0.6297  
y1            1.6133     1.8469   0.874   0.3847  
y2            5.3859     3.4441   1.564   0.1213  
y3            8.5756     3.6705   2.336   0.0217 *
y4            1.7539     1.5106   1.161   0.2487  
y0:z          0.0715     0.1214   0.589   0.5573  
y1:z         -0.1070     0.1376  -0.778   0.4389  
y2:z         -0.4419     0.3266  -1.353   0.1793  
y3:z         -0.7642     0.3363  -2.273   0.0254 *
y4:z              NA         NA      NA       NA
```

**Why with contr.treatment we still have `y0:z`?**

Comment: Do you mean because "`Type4:Ca`" is listed in the output? Can you add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: @gung sorry for that, I tried to make an example. So models `x~y+y:z` and `x~y+z+y:z` seem to be the same, so maybe `y0:z` is a kind of `z`

Comment: Thanks, we'll try to migrate this to [SO] (where you can get an answer) now.

Comment: While there's a programming aspect to this (along the lines of "why does R work this way") I think the underlying issue here is primarily statistical ("how do contrasts work when you leave out main effects") and I think this should remain here until it's clear the issue isn't statistical. Indeed while the Q could be more clearly/concisely presented, I think it should also remain open.

Comment: @Glen_b The reason I voted to close was the lack of a reproducible example. Now there is one, I'm satisfied that this question should be opened - but I'm unsure whether it is a better fit for SO or CV. (Even if it is an issue with R, it strikes me as a *statistical issue concerning R*, so I probably lean towards keeping it here.)